# Highlighting Labels if Mandatory box in blank

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I am in need of assistance.

I need to create a case that will highlight the text box if left blank.

i.e. if CustName = "" then (highlight and set focus)

my reason for using a case rather than a simple if statement is that there are 7 mandatory input box boxes.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question. Then edit your question to make it a good one. Before that, don't expect answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate form's input using simple jQuery.

i.e

`<input type="text" name="CustName" class="input-box" />`

Just validate this input using the jQuery on submit event.

```
$("#form-id").submit(function (event) {
  if ($("CustName").val() == '') {
    $("CustName").focus(); // To set the focus on this text box
    $("CustName").addClass("highlight"); // To highlight input box
  }
}
```